# mocha-phantomjs output not shown when run with Python subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, subprocess, phantomjs, mocha.js, mocha-phantomjs

Guessing this is something to do with STDOUT/STDERR redirection, but the console output is not displayed when running

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output('mocha-phantomjs static/js/tests/headless.html'.split())
```

The same command in the terminal prints out all the test output

Comment: Calling check_output on Nose tests `./manage.py test` displays STDOUT which is what threw me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_output()` captures subprocess' stdout. Use `check_call()` to avoid redirecting stdout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(['mocha-phantomjs', 'static/js/tests/headless.html'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should print the output...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output('mocha-phantomjs static/js/tests/headless.html'.split()))
```

Comment: Ah, can't believe I missed this!  What threw me is the second call I was making to run Python tests with Nose was still outputting to STDOUT without explicitly printing in the Python script.